# git clean isn't cleaning hidden files

Tags: git

I have 3 untracked files in my working directory:

```
$ git sta
## features/subchecks...upstream/BR_4_1_4 [ahead 4]
?? Applications/ETM/Build/Android/.project
?? Applications/zFacebook/Build/Android/.project
?? Core/Barcode/Build/Android/.project
```

I do a dry run of `git clean` like so:

```
$ git clean -n
```

But it's not showing any files will be cleaned. Why is it not cleaning the `.project` files? I'm using msysgit 1.9.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `git clean` for this won't work, but the following did work for me and only cleaned what I saw in git status:

```
$ rm $(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard)
```

Comment: If you want to make that command whitespace friendly, you can use `git ls-files --exclude-standard -oz | xargs -0 rm -f`

Answer (score 6):

To put the tree back into a fully clean slate and get rid of everything  locally that is not tracked by git, do the following:

```
git clean -fdx
```

If you want to keep files that are ignored by git (i.e. files in *.gitignore*) then leave the "x" off.

Answer (score 3):

it's because you need to add `-d` to `git clean` to have it clean directories as well:

```
% git help clean

OPTIONS
       -d
           Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. If an untracked directory is managed by a different Git repository, it is not
           removed by default. Use -f option twice if you really want to remove such a directory.
```

Comment: I can't specify the `d` option because then it will say it's cleaning way more files than necessary. Directories that contain nothing but ignored files (but the directory itself isn't ignored) will be marked for deletion and I don't want that. Basically every untracked file and/or directory that appears in git status should be removed, nothing more.

Comment: then what you want is @RobertDailey's solution

Comment: @zmo Where may I find such a solution?